# Nav Buttons don't match in different browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, navigation

I cannot figure out how to make the length of the buttons on my side navigation match in each browser.  In FF, the buttons seem to match the length of the featured image that they're placed next to.  But in Chrome and IE10, the buttons don't come all the way down.

The website is a WordPress site using the [WP-Forge framework](http://themeawesome.com/responsive-wordpress-theme/), which itself is based off of Foundation.

Website Link: http://www.josephruscitti.com/clients/vazzo/

My CSS

```
.side-nav{
padding:0;
}
.side-nav li{
background: #6698ff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6698ff 0%, #207cca 49%, #527acc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6698ff), color-stop(49%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#527acc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6698ff 0%,#207cca 49%,#527acc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6698ff 0%,#207cca 49%,#527acc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6698ff 0%,#207cca 49%,#527acc 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6698ff 0%,#207cca 49%,#527acc 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6698ff', endColorstr='#527acc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
margin:0;
}

.side-nav li a{
color:#FFF;
font-size:1.4em;
font-weight:bold;
padding:24.5px 10px;
text-indent:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Joseph, you will find that you get a much better response if you post your code not just a link, either in a Jfiddle or on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.side-nav li {
    margin: 0px 0px 0.4375rem;
    font-size: 0.84rem; /* <- CHANGE THIS */
}
```

and give height to the nav box:

```
.side-nav li a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-indent: 10px;
    height: 63px;     /* ADD HEIGHT */
    padding: 24px 10px; /* CHANGE PADDING */
}
```

Work on Chrome and FF... Good luck